# single or multiple docker containers per host

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

So we are in the phase of designing a pipeline for deploying our app to production.
We have 5 services that needs to talk each other, and currently using docker for developing.
We are studying CodePipeline (github + CodeBuild + EB) for deploying, but we have doubts if using Elastic Beanstalk for single container (i.e. 1 container running per host), or multiple (multiple containers running in the same hosts)
The only benefit I can see from using multicontainer is that is cost effective (more cheap to have a fleet of ec2 instance for all containers, than to have a whole fleet for running only 1 container).
Other than that, I can only see extra complexity added in multicontainers, due to the orchestration and task scheduling for managing multiple containers in multiple hosts.
So what is best practice? 1 container per host? or multiple container per host?

Comment: If you're only running one docker container per host you miss out on many of the benefits of containerization. Suggest you look a bit harder at managed container offerings such as ECS / EKS / Fargate.

Answer (score 2):

Single Docker Beanstalk is great when you are just starting out with Docker. Its easy and familiar to use but wastes resources.

Multi-Docker is more advanced, and but basically follows all the same deployment practices of Single Docker and Beanstalk in general. Multi-Docker will provision an ECS cluster for you and launch task (not a service) on each instance. Beanstalk scripts monitor the state of the task and an upstart script is in charge of starting/stopping the task (it leverages ecs agent to do this). There really isn't any added complexity as Beanstalk takes care of all of that.

Each instance will only run 1 task, so tasks scale linearly with instances in the cluster, which makes it only slightly less wasteful than Single Docker, and will cost the same amount (assuming applications of equal size and scaling similarly). The only REAL benefit of Multi-Docker over Single Docker is being able to decouple parts of an application.

If you start using Multi-Docker, you will very quickly move on to ECS as it is all-around better for running containers. If you start with Single Docker, you will quickly get annoyed by the limitations of a single container, and either move on to Multi-Docker or ECS Native. My suggestion is just to skip Beanstalk altogether, or use Multi-Docker to get a feel and understanding of ECS before jumping ship like most people do.

tl;dr The best practice for running containers is setting up a cluster, not using Beanstalk.

p.s. Now with Fargate, you don't even have to manage a cluster at all.